# Unity3D / Vuforia can PAUSE the image target or Game Object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to "freeze" or hold the active 3D object on the camera without target image "physical" pointed at the device camera.

I tried many things to keep / freeze GameObjet on the camera, follow the links:
https://developer.vuforia.com/resources/api/class_q_c_a_r_1_1_image_tracker#a3d5fce135919fe8c02ef69bad9e2b613

and 
https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/ios/dataset-loading-name

This is the closest I get, but things to "get active target", store it in a variable and use it when the "tracker is lost", does not work well. I believe they are old documents and with the new, hinted that it is not possible to do what I am trying.

Follows as close as I could get something:

```
private DataSet dataSet;

void Update ()
{
    if (Input.touchCount> 0)
    {

        ImageTracker imgTracker = TrackerManager.Instance.GetTracker<ImageTracker>() as ImageTracker;
        dataSet = (DataSet) imgTracker.GetActiveDataSets();

        if (IsToFreeze)
        {
            imgTracker.ActivateDataSet (dataSet);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the error i get when i try to ActivateDataSet:

```
InvalidCastException: Can not cast from source type to destination type.
```

If what i said is confusing, please, tell me to improve my english ( im from Brazil ).

Thanks for read and help!

Answer (score 0):

`imgTracker.GetActiveDataSets();` will return an array
so use
 `imgTracker.GetActiveDataSet();` instead
 or you have to loop through the array and activate it

```
IEnumerable dataSet = imageTracker.GetActiveDataSets();

        foreach (DataSet d in dataSet)
        {
            imageTracker.ActivateDataSet(d);
        }
```

Comment: But im follow the right path ? Pause the object ? PS: i will try this in a minute, thanks

Comment: doesnt work, the error says: "Could not activate dataset.
UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
ImageTrackerImpl:ActivateDataSet(DataSet)
testFreeze:Update() (at Assets/testFreeze.cs:42)"

Comment: did you used  `imgTracker.GetActiveDataSet();` ? and it just said it couldn't it didnt said why (more information on error is needed)

Comment: imgTracker.GetActiveDataSet() dos not exists, i use with s at the end like you write. And no, only this error, this is pretty sad to me too.. When a debug the FOREACH, the DataSet is implemented